# How to create an Angular Interceptor to run with promises

Tags: angular, promise, angular-http-interceptors

I have an Angular 9 application that uses an SDK to interact with an API. The return types of the functions in this SDK (i.e. get(), list(), create(), patch()) are all promises. I would like to create an interceptor for these requests so I can add my own loading indicators. Unfortunately my interceptor will only work with observables. Does anyone know how to create an interceptor to handle promise based requests in angular? Here is a snippet of my interceptor code:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('intercepted');
    ...
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interceptor should work with an angular request that has been converted to promise using the toPromise() function. Are you sure your interceptor is being resolved by the sdk?

Comment: HttpIntercepter is typed to return an Observable. You could use rxjs `from` to convert the promises from your SDK to observables https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from